# laravel - orderby doesn't show correct results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a fairly simple query which I load and add an element to the object and then sort it based on that custom element. I'd like to take 20 records or paginate it but when I do so, alot of data vanishes.

This is my code. The piece below gets all the records.

`$fighters = Fighter::all();`

The below code gets the points which is in a function and adds it to the fighter, fighterPoints does not initially exist in the collection, it is created and populated below.

```
foreach ($fighters as $fighter) {
 $fighter->fighterPoints = $fighter->getFighterPoints($fighter->id);
}
```

Then i'd like to sort everything by those fighterPoints with the below function.

```
$sorted = $fighters ->sortByDesc(function ($item, $key) {
  return $item->fighterPoints ;
});
```

When i do this i get all the records which are around 9000, it then sorts on the fighterPoints correctly:
The first record being something like [FighterName, 21309]

When i do `$fighters = Fighter::paginate(20);` it simply starts with [FighterName384, 200] which should be [FighterName, 21309] and just 20 results. The same thing happens with ::take(20) method.

What am I doing wrong here? I am laravel 8.

Comment: Wouldnt the sorted results be in `$sorted`? So when you paginate you need to use that?

Comment: Can't use ->paginate on the $sorted function.

Answer (score 1):

You want to paginate your $sorted variable right?!
To do that you have to

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator; // add
use Illuminate\Support\Collection; // add
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator; //add

...(your code)

// add
public function paginate($items, $perPage = 5, $page = null, $options = [])
{
    $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
    $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);
    return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options);
}
```

then, use that $sorted this way:

```
$fighters = $this->paginate($sorted);
```

reference:https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-6-paginate-with-collection-or-arrayexample.html

—————- EDIT ————

Sorry I misunderstood your question!
If you want to order eloquent, here is how you do it

```
$fighters = Fighter::orderBy('fighterPoints', 'desc')->paginate(20);
```

I hope that’s what you are looking for!

Comment: Well i'd want to paginate the large query, this works but the page is still too slow.

Comment: This is clear however, fighterPoints doesn't exist yet on the model, it gets added to the collection in that foreach.

Comment: Declare getFighterPoints method inside your Fighter model. Then, use that method in your view, when you loop it! So you can get fighter points for each 20 fighters!!